# equivalent of Oracles sys_context ('USERENV', 'SESSIONID') in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm looking for the equivalent of oracle's

```
select sys_context ('USERENV', 'SESSIONID') from dual
```

on MS SQL Server.

I've googled this and found a lot of examples with sys.sysprocesses, sp_who, @@SPID

However @@SSPID seems to have a different meaning than the sessionid in oracle as it appears to be reused over the time. Is there a session identifier on MSSQL server that will not be reused?

Comment: The ORACLE `sessionid` is also [reused](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:65212348056), eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `connection_id` from `sys.dm_exec_connections`. In this view `connection_id` GUID looks like it might do your trick.

```
select connection_id, * from sys.dm_exec_connections
```